# Video Streaming using java

Tags: java, video, streaming

i want to do on thing that after uploding video using code i want to create samll video preview of that video not thumbnail.
can u suggest this service is better for me ?

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of api available.

I recommend to use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler).
Examples can be found [here](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/tree/master/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos) where you can get the code for making preview.

Here is a tutorial for [capturing frames and create video](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-frames-capture-video.html), which can be used as preview.

Or else you can use [vlcj](https://code.google.com/p/vlcj/)